# How can I find the intersection of a list and a nested list?

Tags: python, list, set, intersection, nested-lists

I have a list of fruits:

```
fruits = ["apple","banana"]
```

I also have a nested list of baskets, in which each list contains a string (the name of the basket) and a list of fruits.

```
baskets = [["basket1",["apple","banana","pear","strawberry"]],["basket2",["strawberry","pear","peach"]],["basket3",["peach","apple","banana"]]]
```

I would like to know which baskets contain every fruits in the list fruits: the result I expect is a list with two elements, "basket1" and "basket3".

I figured that intersections would the cleanest way of achieving that, and I tried the following:

```
myset = set(fruits).intersection(*map(set, set(baskets)))
```

But I'm getting a TypeError "unhashable type: 'list'". I understand that I can't map lists, but I thought that using the function "set" on both lists would convert them to sets... is there any other way I can find the intersection of a list and a list of lists?

Comment: why don't you use dictionary for baskets?

Comment: @Sasa Would it make a difference?

Comment: @kormak: Not a _huge_ one in this case, but yes. Instead of having to look at the second element of each list in the `baskets` list, you'd just look at each value in the `baskets` dict. In general, using the right data structure for the job makes your life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over baskets and check if the `fruits` set is a [subset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) of fruits in current basket, if yes store current basket's name.

```
>>> fruits = {"apple", "banana"} #notice the {}, or `set(["apple","banana"])` in Python 2.6 or earlier
>>> [b for b, f in baskets if fruits.issubset(f)]
['basket1', 'basket3']
```

Comment: I get the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'issubset'
The doc says that issubset applies to sets, do I need to convert the lists to sets? If so, how? As I mentioned in my post, using set(fruits) or set(baskets) raises an unhashable type error.

Comment: @kormak: No, `set(fruits)` doesn't raise an unhashable type error, it's `set(baskets)` that does that—which Ashwini isn't doing. (This is why cramming a bunch of expressions into one big expression makes debugging harder. You have no idea which of those many calls to `set` is raising.)

Comment: @kormak: Also, notice that Ashwini is defining `fruits` as a set in the first place, so the issue doesn't even come up.

Comment: @kormak In my code fruits is already a set(notice the `{}`). With `fruits = ["apple","banana"]` there's no way Python will raise such error. And you can keep the `baskets` list as is.

Comment: I see now, I hadn't noticed that!

Answer (score 0):

You can't hash sets any more than you can hash lists. They both have the same problem: because they're mutable, a value can change its contents, making any set that contains it as a member or any dictionary that contains it as a key suddenly invalid.

You *can* hash the immutable equivalents of both, `tuple` and `frozenset`.

---

Meanwhile, your immediate problem is ironically created by your attempt to solve this problem. Break this line down into pieces:

```
myset = set(fruits).intersection(*map(set, set(baskets)))
```

The first piece is this:

```
baskets_set = set(baskets)
```

You've got a list of lists. You, `set(baskets)` is trying to make a set of lists. Which you can't do, because lists aren't hashable.

---

If you just removed that, and used `map(set, baskets)`, you would then have an iterator of sets, which is a perfectly valid thing.

Of course as soon as you try to iterate it, it will try to make a set out of the first element of `baskets`, which is a list, so you'll run into the error again.

---

Plus, even if you solve this, the logic still doesn't make any sense. What's the intersection of a set of, say, 3 strings with a set of, say, 3 (frozen)sets of strings? It's empty. The two sets don't have any elements in common. The fact that some elements of the second one may contain elements of the first doesn't mean that the second one itself contains any elements of the first.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way using your approach:

```
fruits = ["apple","banana"]
baskets = [["basket1",["apple","banana","pear","strawberry"]],
           ["basket2",["strawberry","pear","peach"]],
           ["basket3",["peach","apple","banana"]]]

fruitset = set(fruits)
res =  set(b for b, s in ((b, set(c)) for b, c in baskets) if s & fruitset)
print res  # --> set(['basket1', 'basket3'])
```